# Spraying paint - respirator alternative?

Tags: spraypainting

I am working on building several sets of shutters and the finish will be a low sheen acrylic enamel sprayed on. I tried an N95 mask I had but it did nothing for the vapors. I had a P100 with organic vapor cartridges respirator that I used previously for things like this but the rubber parts dried and cracked.  I have not been able to find a replacement respirator for use in spray painting due to current events.  Is there an alternative or should I be looking in places other than the usual home centers and online stores?

Comment: You might just need to wait for current events to work themselves out. You either need supplied fresh air or carbon ("organic vapor") filters (trust me, the cartridges were also shot if the mask they go with had cracked) or else you need to alter your finish to something less toxic to work with (you may never go back)

Comment: yeah that's pretty much it either get the right filters or use a mask supplied with fresh air, maybe you can make some sort of snorkle hose.

Comment: Scuba certification! Then you can carry the tank on your back. I actually have done this on a alcohol based paint used in food services. But it is a possibility.

Comment: Yes, there are certain high potency paints that strongly recommend SCBA.  (you aren't obliged to use the paint underwater :)

Comment: Any recommendations for a finish less toxic that is tough and long lasting as an enamel paint?  

Re: SCUBA - the university pool is closed through August, (yep I used to swim there 3 days a week till March 15).  There are no SCUBA classes anytime soon...not really a possibility for something I need to do while the wood sits unfinished.